# lightning Design system with javascript framework for togglecheckbox

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am new to LDS and trying to develop a component with Lightning design systems toggle checkbox and my goal is to hide and show certain input label when toggle is enabled and disabled , my questions

1)how would i know the events and attributes of LDS toggle checkbox?
2)onclick,tried onchange isnt working so i think this is not the right event.
3)while the same event works fine with inputcheckbox and am able to achieve whatever functionality i need

```
<aura:component>
<div class="slds-form-element">
<label class="slds-checkbox--toggle slds-grid">
<span class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom--none">Do You Have More 
Information</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" aria-describedby="toggle-desc" />
<span id="toggle-desc" class="slds-checkbox--faux_container" aria-
live="assertive">
 <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
 <span class="slds-checkbox--on" onclick="{!c.run}">Yes</span>
 <span class="slds-checkbox--off" >No</span>
</span>
</label>
</div>
<aura:component>
```

below works fine and is able to fire run event

```
<ui:inputcheckbox value="{!v.check}" click="{!c.run}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the [lightning:input (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) component with `type="toggle"`. This keeps you in the world of Lightning Components rather than having to integrate raw HTML elements with Lightning Components.

The output is illustrated in [Mohith Shrivastava](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/645/mohith-shrivastava)'s Wiki page [Lightning Base Components Designer Guide](https://github.com/msrivastav13/Base-Lightning-Components/wiki/Lightning-Base-Components-Designer-Guide).